# Why the 1 TB disk limit on Thermaltake Blacx?

Tags: storage

I've been looking at options for external storage and I quite like the idea of plug hard drives in as needed like you can with [Thermaltake's Blacx](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?S=1268&ID=1642). The USB 2 speed limit doesn't really concern me but I'm a bit puzzled by the 1 TB limit to the disks it will work with.

It seems to me that it should work with any SATA compatible disk. So why the limit? Is this perhaps a purely artificial limit so they can sell us a new unit in a few years (the price per gigabyte sweet spot is already moving to 1.5 TB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm a bit puzzled by the 1 TB
>   limit to the disks it will work with.

umm ... it says (under [Features](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?S=1268&ID=1642#Tab0) as well as under [Specifications](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?S=1268&ID=1642#Tab1)):

> "Supports All 2.5” & 3.5” SATA HDDs up
>   to **2 TB** !"
>
> "HDD Capacity: All 2.5” or 3.5” SATA
>   HDD up to **2 TB**"
>
> Patented Design:
>   2.5” & 3.5” USB SATAHDD Docking Station, Supports All 2.5” & 3.5” SATA
>   Hard Drives up to **2 TB** !!

and AFAIK, 2 TB HDDs are the largest available consumer hard disc drives available as of now.

Comment: indeed.  maybe OP is looking at a retailer's outdated info page -- or worse, outdated stock.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at a retailers page. Also, all reviews I found cited the same specs. I failed to notice that Termaltake's site specifies 2 TB. The question remains though, why specify a limit? Is it merely the maximum that they've tested it against?

Comment: Yes, this is the maximum they have tested against.

Comment: as i said, 2 TB is the maximum size for consumer disks available at the moment. so, they play it safe and claim they're compatible with what is available at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (11.27.2014), only the base model of this product has the 2TB limit.  All newer models, and I quote:

"Supports all 2.5" & 3.5" SATA I/II/III hard drives in ALL Capacities"

That is great news that the new models do not have any size limit on them.

Go for the 2 slot model.  I have it and it is fantastic.

Links with further information:
[Single bay unit](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/products-model_Specification.aspx?id=C_00002058)
[Dual bay unit](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817153146)

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for answering this question.  Could you add a link in your answer for where the information can be found?

Comment: Hi fixer1234.  Here you go:

Single Drive Unit - 
http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/products-model.aspx?id=C_00002058

Dual Drive Unit - 
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817153146
Scroll down and then select Specifications.

Please let me know if that is not what you were looking for.

Comment: Looks like conflicting information on the dual bay unit.  In one place, it says it's limited to 3 TB/bay.  Right below that on the same page, it says "all capacities".  I supposed that wouldn't be inconsistent if no 3.5" drives exceed 3 TB.  However, the 1 TB limit in the question appears to be gone.  Thanks for the links.  I added them to your answer.